# Is using type aliases for STL Containers bad practice if your team agrees upon a set of aliases?

Tags: c++

Is there anything wrong with doing stuff like this to protect the code from too many std::'s?

```
// These underscore_cased type aliases make my code shorter and easier to read for me. 
// For Example:
template<class T> using v=std::vector<T>;
template<class T, class U> using u_m=std::unordered_map<T,U>;
template<class T> using p_q=std::priority_queue<T>;
template<class T,class U> using u_mm=unordered_multimap<T,U>;
```

Or is this risky behavior?

I don't see how this would pollute my namespace like using namespace std would.

Comment: It make think harder for newcomers to know the aliases.

Comment: You might still have some appropriate `using std::vector<T>;` at top of your cpp to avoid to prefix with `std::`.

Comment: Nonsense names like "u_m"  should not be found in any code anywhere.

Comment: following @Jarod42 comment, a simple `using` at the top of cpp files avoid the need for many `std`. and `u_m` is a name that I find meanigless for a variable, not to mention for a type

Comment: @GianPaolo using namespace std; would result in namespace pollution, but I don't think my solution does.

Comment: I'm referring to the `using` suggested by @Jarod42, not to the blamed `using namespace std`

Comment: @GianPaolo oh, gotcha now, thanks. I had no idea you could do that.

Comment: These look like an attempt to make names shorter while type aliases should be used to express logical connections. That is use of `vec<T>` should not imply use of `std::vector`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My main concern with your suggested names would be that they lead to unexpected errors when you try to use them as variable names. Having a local variable called `vec` is pretty standard stuff.

Note that this kind of problem is usually avoided simply due to naming conventions: For example, in most C++ code bases, types start with capital letters and are `CamelCased`, whereas local variables start with a lowercase letter (this is also how the syntax highlighting on Stackoverflow works btw). It's not commonly a problem that the `std` names follow a different convention **because** they are in their own namespace. You cannot name a variable `std::vector`.

Basically, your suggested aliases break with this and open you up to all the annoying problems and "unreadabilities" that these conventions were supposed to eliminate.

Comment: I updated the question and upvoted your answer even though the part about camelCasing has now been fixed. Do you still see a problem?

Comment: @user3586940 The identifiers you introduce with your `using` are still types (or type aliases to be precise) so they should start with a capital letter. However, once you do that, I wouldn't really have objections about your idea.

Comment: I still found "funny" that we use convention incompatible with std.

Answer (score 4):

Doing this:

1. Makes your code harder to read.
2. Pollutes the namespace (perhaps the global one) with `vec` and `u_m`.

C++ is reasonably terse as it is. My suggestion would be to get used to `std::`.

There's nothing wrong with a `using` or a `typedef` within the confines of a `class` though. That can even be useful; allowing you to change the components of the definition without having to change dependent code.

Comment: suppose my team and I find std::vector<std::vector<int>> harder to read than vec<vec<int>>. Could you give an example where namespace pollution would be an issue?

Comment: @user3586940: Facetiously, some like-minded idiosyncrat might have *almost* the same idea, and you end up using some of their code, then you have the mother of all clashes.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Feelin' better ;-)

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Couldn't resist basing it from 0 in the markdown though.

Comment: @Bathsheba but in that case, you would have two identical type aliases, and the code wouldn't compile, no?

Comment: @user3586940: Which is sort of like a problem innit?

Comment: _"C++ is reasonably terse as it is."_ Sorry, but have you ever used `std::remove` (I know you have)? You have to repeat the container name no less than 4 times... /rant

Answer (score 3):

The CppCoreGuidlines written by Bjarne Stroustrup and Herb Sutter has a guideline about this titled:
[Use template aliases to simplify notation and hide implementation details](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines.html#t42-use-template-aliases-to-simplify-notation-and-hide-implementation-details).

The reason given is:

> Improved readability. Implementation hiding. Note that template aliases replace many uses of traits to compute a type. They can also be used to wrap a trait.

Note that the examples given under this guideline are not in global namespace.

However, you should also ensure that such aliases are not redundant for that might affect performance as per another [guideline](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines.html#per12-eliminate-redundant-aliases).

Comment: The guideline is a general one. I do not know all the variations/scopes in which the OP wants to use these aliases. Anyway, I had mentioned that the examples given under the guideline are not in global namespace.